# I need Freemarker documentation for data model when using #recurse with trees other than XML

Tags: java, freemarker

I am trying to process a tree structure in Freemarker and would like use the #recurse, #visit directives but I can't find any good documentation on how to set up the data model.  The only examples I can see are those that create a data model for an XML structure.  I don't need it to be so detailed.  My tree is very simple.

In trying to test the functionality I need, I built a unit test but when I run it I get

```
FreeMarker template error:
For "." left-hand operand: Expected a hash, but this has evaluated to a node
```

Here is the source code:

```
public class FreemarkerXmlTests {

    static class Element implements TemplateNodeModel {
        private final String name;
        private final String text;
        private Element parent;
        private final List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>();

        public Element(String name) {
            this(name, null);
        }

        public Element(String name, String text) {
            this.name = name;
            this.text = text;
        }

        public void add(Element element) {
            element.parent = this;
            this.elements.add(element);
        }

        public List<Element> getElements() {
            return this.elements;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return this.text;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public TemplateModel get(String key) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public TemplateNodeModel getParentNode() throws TemplateModelException {
            return this.parent;
        }

        @Override
        public TemplateSequenceModel getChildNodes() throws TemplateModelException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new SimpleSequence(this.elements, cfg.getObjectWrapper());
        }

        @Override
        public String getNodeName() throws TemplateModelException {
            return this.name;
        }

        @Override
        public String getNodeType() throws TemplateModelException {
            return this.name;
        }

        @Override
        public String getNodeNamespace() throws TemplateModelException {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static Configuration cfg;
    private static final String myTestTemplate = "<#recurse doc>\r\n" +
            "\r\n" +
            "<#macro book>\r\n" +
            "  Book element with title ${.node.title} \r\n" +
            "    <#recurse>\r\n" +
            "  End book\r\n" +
            "</#macro>\r\n" +
            "\r\n" +
            "<#macro title>\r\n" +
            "  Title element\r\n" +
            "</#macro>\r\n" +
            "\r\n" +
            "<#macro chapter>\r\n" +
            "  Chapter element with title: ${.node.title}\r\n" +
            "</#macro>";

    @BeforeClass
    public static void classInit() throws IOException {

        StringTemplateLoader stringTemplateLoader = new StringTemplateLoader();
        stringTemplateLoader.putTemplate("myTestTemplate", myTestTemplate);

        cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_29);
        cfg.setTemplateLoader(stringTemplateLoader);
        cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
        cfg.setLogTemplateExceptions(false);
        cfg.setWrapUncheckedExceptions(true);
        cfg.setFallbackOnNullLoopVariable(false);
    }

    @Test
    public void basicXmlTest() throws TemplateException, IOException {

        Element doc = new Element("doc");

        Element book = new Element("book");
        book.add(new Element("title", "Test Book"));
        doc.add(book);

        Element chapter1 = new Element("chapter");
        chapter1.add(new Element("title", "Ch1"));
        chapter1.add(new Element("para", "p1.1"));
        chapter1.add(new Element("para", "p1.2"));
        chapter1.add(new Element("para", "p1.3"));
        book.add(chapter1);

        Element chapter2 = new Element("chapter");
        chapter2.add(new Element("title", "Ch2"));
        chapter2.add(new Element("para", "p2.1"));
        chapter2.add(new Element("para", "p2.2"));
        chapter2.add(new Element("para", "p2.3"));
        book.add(chapter2);

        Map<String, Object> root = new HashMap<>();
        // Put string "user" into the root
        root.put("doc", doc);

        Template temp = cfg.getTemplate("myTestTemplate");

        Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
        temp.process(root, out);

    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`freemarker.template.TemplateNodeModel`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/TemplateNodeModel.html) interface. Your objects have to implement that, or they have to be wrapped (via the [`ObjectWrapper`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/ObjectWrapper.html)) into a [`TemplateModel`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/TemplateModel.html) the implements that. Then `#recurse`/`#visit`/`?parent`/`?children`/etc. will work with them.

Here's an example of implementing [`TemplateNodeModel`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/TemplateNodeModel.html) for traversing JSON: https://github.com/freemarker/fmpp/blob/master/src/main/java/fmpp/models/JSONNode.java

Some templates where above is used:
https://github.com/freemarker/fmpp/tree/master/src/test/resources/tests/dl_json/src

As of the `.` operator, for that you need to implement `TemplateHashModel` (or its sub-interfaces, like `TemplateHashModelEx2`).

Comment: Very useful examples.  This helped me fix my bug.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the examples posted by ddekany, I added the following:

1. implements TemplateHashModel to the Element class

```
    static class Element implements TemplateNodeModel, TemplateHashModel {
```

2. a method to the Element class and the unit test worked:

```
        @Override
        public TemplateModel get(String key) throws TemplateModelException {

            switch (key) {
            case "title":
            case "name":
                return cfg.getObjectWrapper().wrap(this.name);

            default:
                throw new TemplateModelException("unknown hash get: " + key);
            }
        }
```